# Do unresummed self-energy functions spoil RGE resummation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory, self-energy

I am aware, that the solution of the $\beta$-function contains a resummation of all large logarithms, but I fail to understand how this is actually relevant: The coupling constant is not an observable so when I calculate a cross-section, it needs to be combined with a self-energy function that will contain unresummed large logs.

Here are a two examples:

1. Suppose I determined the QED coupling $\alpha(\mu=m_e)$ at low energy. Now I can use the RGE to rescale the coupling to lets say $\mu=M_Z$. The coupling $\alpha(\mu=M_Z)$ will then contain a resummation of all large logs, but the self-energy $\Sigma(q^2=M_Z^2,\mu=M_Z, m_e)$ will still contain $\log\frac{m_e^2}{q^2}$ and $\log\frac{\mu^2}{m_e^2}$ at leading order (only leading order; no resummation).
2. If measuring $\alpha(\mu=M_Z)$ and then computing $\alpha(\mu=m_e)$ using the RGE, a low energy calculation seems to be free of large logarithms as $m_e$ is the only present scale.
   However, the coupling $\alpha(\mu=M_Z)$ is determined from an observed cross-section by using the self-energy function $\Sigma(q^2=M_Z^2,\mu=M_Z, m_e)$. So in that case, the initial value $\alpha(\mu=M_Z)$ already suffers from large logs.

If there are multiple particles with different masses, it just gets worse. The only way out seems to be a resummation of the self-energy contributions as well. But If I do that, why do I need to apply the RGE anyway?

Comment: I think it would help to consider a specific observable. The RG equations are of the form d/d(logM) G^n(q_1,..q_n)=0, which explicitly involves the full n-point Green fct (here M is an arbitary normalization point). The beta function is just one ingredient that goes int solving this equation. In general, we also need the running mass parameters, wave function renormalization, etc.

Comment: You're right, there is a bit more to it. But after all, the "issue" remains. Either I resum all corrections in which case I do not need the RGE or I will have contributions in which the large logs are not resummed.